# jquery keyboard with multiple fields

Tags: jquery

I am looking for a simple way that allow me when on focus on the input field and allow me to use the jquery keyboard, the problem is when i type into another field after first it will grab all the value from all inputs.

```
$('.controls input').focus(function(evt){
    /*
        jQuery Keyboard
        =============================================================
    */
    var $write = $(this),
    shift = false,
    capslock = false;

    $('#keyboard li').click(function(){
        var $this = $(this),
            character = $this.html(); // If it's a lowercase letter, nothing happens to this variable

        // Shift keys
        if ($this.hasClass('left-shift') || $this.hasClass('right-shift')) {
            $('.letter').toggleClass('uppercase');
            $('.symbol span').toggle();

            shift = (shift === true) ? false : true;
            capslock = false;
            return false;
        }

        // Caps lock
        if ($this.hasClass('capslock')) {
            $('.letter').toggleClass('uppercase');
            capslock = true;
            return false;
        }

        // Delete
        if ($this.hasClass('delete')) {
            var html = $write.html();

            $write.html(html.substr(0, html.length - 1));
            return false;
        }

        // Special characters
        if ($this.hasClass('symbol')) character = $('span:visible', $this).html();
        if ($this.hasClass('space')) character = ' ';
        if ($this.hasClass('tab')) character = "\t";
        if ($this.hasClass('return')) character = "\n";

        // Uppercase letter
        if ($this.hasClass('uppercase')) character = character.toUpperCase();

        // Remove shift once a key is clicked.
        if (shift === true) {
            $('.symbol span').toggle();
            if (capslock === false) $('.letter').toggleClass('uppercase');

            shift = false;
        }

        // Add the character
        $write.val($write.val() + character);
    });
})
```

Comment: Return true if an element has got no focus.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked to the .keypress(), .keyup() and .keydown() method of jQuery ?

http://api.jquery.com/category/events/